# Release the same app in two different AppStores (countries)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

I'm facing a tricky situation. I'm building an MVP app, that is currently avalaible only in one country and our next step is to release it in another country. The thing is, that the other country is going to have completely different data set (25-35MB large). Otherwise the app is same. So what I need is to release it in other country, but as new app (due to the large data set).

What is my plan: I do have 2 build schemes (Germany & UK), 2 submodules (as pods) containing datasets, and Podfile, where I switch between these two data sets based on the build scheme.

When I create release branch I triger CI that creates builds for each scheme. Then I want to upload it to the AppStore. One app will be only avalaible in German AppStore and second one only in the UK (so no spamming the AppStore with a same app).

My idea is to change Bundle ID programatically based on the enviroment, but I don't know how to do it. If you have any other ideas, I'd be happy to hear them. Thanks

Comment: Not downvoting, but what's the specific issue?n If it's all good, then what are you trying to do? Bundle ID is very tightly tied to each app. I'd assume that programmatically changing it involves rather **deep** changes into `info.plist` and maybe more. It sounds (to me) that you are trying to use different Bundle IDs for the same app based on the build? Why not change the schemas? Snd if that doesn't work, then how about a different schema? And if not that - could you provide more details along the line of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @dfd: I updated my question. Thank you for feedback.

Comment: Well, it's in the _Info.plist_ like everything else.

Comment: @matt: Info.plist is read-only.

Comment: Well that depends on whether you try to change it before or after building.

Comment: @matt: My plan was doing it automatically, without any further work from my side. Gnashed already answered and it perfectly fits my needs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the bundle id programmatically. The bundle id is the *identity* of your application, it doesn't make any sense to change it.

It's easy enough to have a project with two build targets, each for a complete application with a different bundle id. You wouldn't do that based on the build scheme, but the target.

PS. Apple doesn't like you to submit *many* different versions of an app. It's a bit like spamming. An app could contain for example 50 datasets that can be downloaded on demand.